# Необходимо сделать юзербота автоответчик на пирограме, код написан, но хочу, чтобы бот отвечал только на 1 сообщение

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Т.е. бот должен отвечать только один раз каждому пользователю

````
from config import txt
from asyncio import sleep
from pyrogram import Client, filters
api_id=13806611
api_hash="ид"
app=Client("account",api_id,api_hash)
@app.on_message()
def avtootvet(client,message):
    if message.chat.type in "private":
        app.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,text=txt)
        time.sleep(0.25)
app.run()```
````

Comment: Что такое "только на 1 сообщение"?

Comment: Т.е. бот отвечает только один раз каждому пользователю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот Ваш полный новый код (*я создал список пользователей, которым бот уже отправлял сообщение*):

```
from config import txt
from asyncio import sleep
from pyrogram import Client, filters
sp_p=[]
api_id=13806611
api_hash="ид"
app=Client("account",api_id,api_hash)
@app.on_message()
def avtootvet(client,message):
    if message.from_user.id not in sp_p:
        if message.chat.type in "private":
            app.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,text=txt)
            time.sleep(0.25)
            sp_p.append(message.from_user.id)
    else: app.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,text='Простите, но Вам я уже слал сообщение!')
app.run()
```

Помогло?

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное!

Comment: @WheelzFun Поставьте галочку на ответе :))